# Batch - Using wget (or similar service) to pass a captcha request

Tags: batch, wget, captcha

I need to download this file...

```
h**p://www.vhannibal.net/download_setting.php?id=1
```

...using `Wget` from promt of dos of my Windows.

Currectly i used GnuWin32 wget 1.11.4.3287......... when i put this link to wget i obtain a php file contain this link:

```
h**p://www.vhannibal.net/recaptcha.php?id=1
```

If i put this link with wget i obtain another php file say to me the code it's wrong....

You can help me to automate the download the file from this page using `wget` ??

Until some day ago i use this batch file working without problems:

```
set VhWget=-U="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
set Link3="h**p://www.vhannibal.net/download_setting.php?id=1&ref=name"
set Link4="h**p://www.vhannibal.net/download_setting.php?id=1&ref=name&action=download&clicked=y"
wget %VhWget% --save-cookies=.\cookie.tmp --keep-session-cookies -q -O ".\temp.php" %Link3% >NUL
ping -n 10 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >NUL
wget %VhWget% --load-cookies=.\cookie.tmp --keep-session-cookies -q -O ".\prova.zip" %Link4% >NUL
```

But now at the second `wget` there is present a captcha code verification.. I can use `wget` to pass it (not skip but pass it.. for example download the jpg of verification and from batch watch it and put on a variable or similar solution) ?

Comment: The entire point of captcha is so that this kind of think can't be done.

Comment: `to pass a captcha request` this will not work.

Comment: hey boys.. i don't need to skip the captcha request.. i need only to view the request out of my browser (like firefox or similar).

I want to obtain a semi-automatic download......

Answer (score 0):

Recaptcha uses a Javascript-based challenge-response mechanism specifically to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. If you really must steal satellite television, you'll just have to download the necessary data by hand.

Comment: And not exist a alternative method to create an interactive input request to user ?
Jdownload for example for recaptcha fields request the user to insert the jpg.... how i can recreate this condition ?

Comment: @Diabolik Your persistence is adorable, but I suspect you're not likely to find much help with your lawbreaking efforts on Super User.

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmm.... i thinks i can't complete to pass the captcha from a batch.
I can try to found a little browser session.... lauch from prompt of dos like:
Firefox.exe link.php

At this point a little gui able to view the captcha request and the field for response.... and a submit button...

Comment: @Diabolik: JDownloader parses the HTML code, identifies the CAPTCHA image, downloads it, tries to OCR it and on failure shows it to the user for manual solving. Feel free to create your own app that does this; you can always use the JD source for inspiration.

Comment: @karan... you are trust, i already have found a method for download jpg of captcha.
I thinks i need to create (using VB.NET.... VisualBasic... or other apps) a mini browser... or a javascript for obtain the captcha and download this file.

Because if i add one of this link on jdownload doesn't found anything to downlad ?